# Induced topology on Circle

Tags: general-topology

The following problem is due to Geroch (Mathematical Physics):

Let $Y$ be a *topological* plane, namely a point of $Y$ is a pair $(y_1,y_2)$ of real numbers. Let $A$ be a subset of $Y$ consisting of all points for which $y_1^1+y_2^2=1$, namely the topological one-sphere. Find **explicitly** the open sets in $A$.

Attempt at solution:

Since $A$ is subset of $Y$, consider $(A,i)$, with $i$ a monomorphism in the category of topological spaces that imbeds $A$ into $Y$. I will try to induce on $A$ the coarsest topology possible that makes $i$ continuous. Therefore it seems natural to define

$$
\mathcal{O}_A=\{i^{-1}\left(Y\right) \ | \ Y\in\mathcal{O}_Y\}.
$$
In other words if $A\in \mathcal{O}_A$, this means that there exists some $Y$ open such that $$A=i^{-1}\left(Y\right)=\{\alpha \in A \ | \ i(\alpha)\in Y\}.$$

Now a typical open set $Y\in\mathcal{O}_Y$ looks like $(u,v)\times (r,s)$ with $u,v,r,s\in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore I should get, for a typical open set in $\mathcal{O}_A$

$$
A = \{ \alpha\in A \ | \ i(\alpha)\in (u,v)\times(r,s)\}.
$$
This is where I get a little bit confused as to what is $i(\alpha)$. How do I incorporate into the monomorphism $i$ the constraint that the image should lie on the unit spehere?

Comment: What's the difference between your "topological plane" and the plane ${\mathbb R}^2$ we are all familiar with? Same question for your "topological one-sphere". Most important: What do you mean by an "explicit" description of the open sets in $A$?

Comment: They are indeed the same, I just followed the notation of the exercise. Just different symbols. That's the statement of the exercise, to state explicitly the open sets in $A$.

Comment: With all due respect (I'm not judging neither the book nor what you've written), but isn't already explicit and clear that the above circle becomes a topological space with the subspace topology induced by $Y$? That is, subsets of it, are open when they are intersections with open subsets of $Y$? Say something like an "open" arc for instance (and unions of them)! Also I believe because it's mathematical physics books means something like a normed two dimensional real vector space with the topology induced by the norm, that's why the terminology.